# PHP bitwise OR vs Javascript bitwise OR

Tags: javascript, php, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Javascript:

```
var a=209348540618090 | 0;//-1050290838
```

PHP:

```
$a= 209348540618090|0;//209348540618090
$a=(209348540618090 & 0xffffffff) | 0;  //3244676458
```

Why is the result of the bitwise operation in PHP different to the bitwise operation in Javascript?

Comment: Bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints (in javascript), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: @bruchowski the operation `& 0xffffffff` is meant to convert the number to 32-bit, even so the result is not the same.